# mac環境CUIでOpenCVを触っていますが.cppファイルがコンパイルできない。

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

MacでHomebrewを使ってOpenCV3をインストールし、
下記「sample.cpp」というファイルを作成しました。

【sample.cpp】

```
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main()
{
  cv::VideoCapture capture(0);
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    cv::Mat readImg;
    capture >> readImg;
    cv::imshow("Captured Image",readImg);
    cv::waitKey(0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

ターミナルから下記文言でコンパイルを試みましたが

```
$ clang++ -o sample sample.cpp
```

下記エラーが表示されました。

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
      _main in sample-b62757.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)", referenced from:
      _main in sample-b62757.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()", referenced from:
      _main in sample-b62757.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)", referenced from:
      _main in sample-b62757.o
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::release() in sample-b62757.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in sample-b62757.o
  "cv::waitKey(int)", referenced from:
      _main in sample-b62757.o
  "cv::fastFree(void*)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::~Mat() in sample-b62757.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

こちらのエラーの原因がわかりません。

また、教本を見ながら下記でコンパイルを試みました。

```
$ clang++ -o sample 'pkg-config --cflags opencv' 'pkg-config --libs opencv' sample.cpp
```

こちらは下記エラーが出力されました。

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config --cflags opencv'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config --libs opencv'
```

ファイルがないのかなと思いましたが下記文言を打ち込むと

```
$ pkg-config --cflags opencv
```

下記のように出力されます。

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13_3/include/opencv -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13_3/include
```

下記文言は

```
$ pkg-config --libs opencv
```

下記のように出力されます。

```
 -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13_3/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
```

いつもc/c++はコンパイルできます。
なぜかopencvだけうまくコンパイルできません。

ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: `'pkg-config --cflags opencv'` の部分ですが、シングルクォートではなくバッククォートか `$()` にすると良いかと思います。`\`pkg-config --cflags opencv\`` or `$(pkg-config --cflags opencv)`  `'pkg-config --libs opencv'` についても同様です。

Comment: metropolisさま

ありがとうございます！
こちらご教授いただいた内容で解決しました！！
ずっと原因が謎だったので感動しすぎて泣きそうです。

本当にありがとうございます。